# correct tenses: [I am doing something.] or [I have done something.]

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-continuous

I have made up the sentences below.

1. (Suppose that I **HAVE** started cleaning the street.)

(a) I said to John, "Today is the six day I have cleaned the street.

(b) I said to John, "Today is the six day I am cleaning the street.

2. (**Suppose that there is a dish of hamburgers on a dish**. I want to show my friends how many I can eat in a row. I **HAVE** taken a bite of a hamburger.)

(a) I said to them, "This is the six burger I have eaten."

(b) I said to them, "This is the six burger I am eating."

Some of my friends think the present perfect is correct. My other friends think the present continuous makes more sense.

I am not sure who is correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For one thing, you need *six**th*** in all of your examples.

Comment: And **a dish of hamburgers on a dish** is tautology.

Comment: @KateBunting I imagined a fast food which had *Hamburgers on a dish* in the menu and somebody asking for a dish of *Hamburgers on a dish*.

Comment: That's totally unidiomatic English.